# Gradient descent - why subtract gradient to update $m$ and $b$

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

These are the gradient descent formulas:
$$\frac{\delta }{\delta m} = \frac{2}{n}\sum-x_i(y_i - mx_i + b)\\
\frac{\delta }{\delta m} = \frac{2}{n}\sum-(y_i - mx_i + b) $$
And my understanding is they come from first taking the positive gradient is the partial derivatives of the function $ (y - mx + b)^2$.

This leads to
$$\frac{\delta J}{\delta m}( 2x(y - mx +b ))\\
\frac{\delta J}{\delta b}(2 \times (y - mx + b) \times 1)$$

Then to get the descent, we just add negatives to each partial derivative. So we are already descending.

But translating gradient descent into code, this is what I often see:

```
def linear_regression(X, y, m_current=0, b_current=0, epochs=1000, 
    learning_rate=0.0001):
    N = float(len(y))
    for i in range(epochs):
   y_current = (m_current * X) + b_current
   cost = sum([data**2 for data in (y-y_current)]) / N
   m_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(X * (y - y_current))
   b_gradient = -(2/N) * sum(y - y_current)
   m_current = m_current - (learning_rate * m_gradient)
   b_current = b_current - (learning_rate * b_gradient)
   return m_current, b_current, cost
```

My question is about the update to `m_current` and `b_current` in the final lines of the function. Why is `m_current - learning rate * m_gradient` and `b_current - learning_rate * b_gradient`?

Why not

```
  m_current = m_current + (learning_rate * m_gradient)
  b_current = b_current + (learning_rate * b_gradient)
```

Our gradient descents are already negative to point us towards descending along the cost curve, so why aren't we updating our `m_current` and `b_current` by just adding the respective gradients?

Comment: In the code, m_gradient and b_gradient are the two components of the gradient, which points in the direction of steepest *ascent*.

Comment: So then where does negative sign come from for the m_gradient and b_gradient.

Comment: Your expression for the gradient included minus signs also. I added an answer with your own minus signs highlighted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we add the gradient to it, we are taking the step that is the steepest ascent, that is we are increasing our value locally, but here we are trying to minimize our objective function.

For example, suppose $y=2x$, the gradient is $2$, no matter where we are, adding $2$ to our current location increases the value of $y$.

Comment: yea - but aren't we already taking the negative when we go from (2x(y−mx+b)) to - (2x(y−mx+b)).  In the code, this is four lines from the bottom.  So why do we do this again in the second to last line?

Comment: I agree with littleO that the gradient itself has a negative sign and m_gradient and b_gradient indeed are the corresponding gradient (rather than their negative).

Answer (score 1):

`m_gradient` and `b_gradient` in the code are the two components of the gradient, which points in the direction of steepest *ascent*.

The objective function that we want to minimize is
$$
J(m,b) = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N (y_i - (m x_i + b))^2.
$$
Notice that I have included parentheses around $m x_i + b$.
As you mentioned, the partial derivatives of $J$ are
\begin{align}
\require{color} \frac{\partial J(m,b)}{\partial m} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \colorbox{yellow}{-}x_i(y_i - (m x_i + b)), \\
\frac{\partial J(m,b)}{\partial b} = \frac{2}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \colorbox{yellow}{-}(y_i - (m x_i + b)).
\end{align}
You included those highlighted minus signs yourself already. These expressions agree perfectly with `m_gradient` and `b_gradient` in the code.

Comment: got it, thanks!